# m2eclipse dependency versions not up to date

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, m2eclipse

I'm using **m2eclipse** plugin to develop maven project in eclipse. While editing **pom.xml** file, I use the **Dependencies** tab in the pom.xml editor to choose dependencies required. Recently I noticed that the dependencies available while searching is not up-to-date.

For eg. The available version in m2eclipse for **spring-aop** is 3.1.3.RELEASE however quick google search gave me version [3.2.1.RELEASE](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/3.2.1.RELEASE) from [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/) . Similarly **spring-asm** was also not up-to-date.

I'm using many dependencies and I don't want to check for up-to-date dependencies manually.

How can the repository in m2eclipse be kept up-to-date, may be sync with mvnrepository.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `Window`, `Show View`, `Other...`, `Maven`, `Maven Repositories` and click OK.  This will open `Maven Repositories` View.  Select `Global Repositories` and right click on `central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`, select either `Rebuild Index` or `Update Index`.  This will make your index up-to-date.